# Cover body with background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a portfolio for the freecodecamp course. I want my portfolio page to have a slide out navigation menu, that slides out once you click on the menu button. I also want to have an image covering the body completely and when the menu slides into the page the picture would move with the body. I already have the slide out menu and the body moves along with the menu as it slides into the viewport, now I just need to figure out a way to add an image to the body that also responds to the slide out menu. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my HTML and JS code that I have written so far.

```
<!DOCTYTPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body class="menu menu-open">
        <header>
            <a href="#" class="menu-toggle">Menu</a>
            <nav class="menu-side">
                This is a side menu
            </nav>
        </header>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function() {
                var body = $('body');
                $('.menu-toggle') .bind('click', function(){
                body.toggleClass('menu-open');
                return false;
                });
            })();

            $(document).ready(function(){

               $(".menu").css({"height":$(window).height() + "px"});

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS.

```
.menu{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left:0;
}

.menu-open{
    left:231px;

}

.menu-open .menu-side{
    left: 0;
}

.menu-side, 
.menu{
    -webkit-transition: left 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.2s ease;
    transition: left 0.2s ease;
}

.menu-side{
    background-color: #333;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:-231px;
    width: 210px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.menu-toggle{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is add a background image to the class you add to the body when the menu is open if I understand the question correctly.

```
    .menu-open {
      background-image: url('your-image.jpg');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a div into a body (so you can have more flexibility to manipulate with the content):

```
<body>
 <nav></nav>
   <div>
     <p>Menu</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

Then use CSS to fill the window with the background and set style of your navigation:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; /* Relative to 100% of the height of the viewport (browser 
                    automatically recognizes height of the window) */ 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Adjust body size to the html */
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Background resizes automatically when menu appears */
  background-image: url('yourimage.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And animate navigation with jQuery:

```
$("p").click(function() {
    $("nav").animate({width:'toggle'}, 350);
});
```

Comment: This might well be a working code/solution. But you should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.